Shred command results in faulty keyboard
On at least three Lenovo Laptops, many keys no longer work following the use of the shred command.

I used a bootable Ubuntu USB key.
Within the Ubuntu OS, in the terminal window:

sudo fdisk -l
sudo shred -n10 -v /dev/nvme0n1


Shred runs its course.
I then install Windows (10)

Then oddly enough, the keyboard doesn't work (many keys are completely non-functional).

In the BIOS, the keyboard works fine.
The hard drive is an NVMe.

How can Ubuntu's shred  result in our keyboards not working?

Have you tried installing Windows over Ubuntu without running shred, and did that leave you with a keyboard without the issues? I.e., can you 100% attribute your keyboard issues in Windows to running shred in Ubuntu and nothing else?

Were handing out Laptops to employees and shredding is a requierment. To answer your qestion, No I cannot assert that Shred is to fault. But I can see no ther logical explanation. txs.,

Try to reproduce the problem without running shred just for testing. To fulfill the requirement you can repeat the process with shred.

Thanks Bodo for your input. ''Try to reproduce the problem without running shred just for testing'' That means just installing windows, which is what we do here every day; without problems.  ''To fulfill the requirement you can repeat the process with shred''  sorry, what is it you want me to do?

Could this be caused by shred deleting firmware files? Could it be removing efivars? See https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/milxpl/can_rm_rf_brick_a_computer_with_uefi/ for example. I doubt it since they do work in the BIOS, but still...


This cannot be possibly true. 2. Running shred more than once for HDDs has been irrelevant for over two decades and it's never been relevant for SSDs/NVMe's as blkdiscard does that a million times faster.


Scrub is 10+ years old.  I'm not sure I trust its detection of a disk block or character device and switch into a fill-the-sectors write mode.  My own approach is to (1) wipe the disk label (i.e., the partitioning), (2) create a whole-disk ext2 filesystem, (3) scrub the filesystem with scrub -X mode, and (4) dd the first few megabytes of the disk to clear the ext2 metadata.  The sectors are still scrubbed the way you want, but you aren't depending on scrub to detect the disk properly and do the right thing.

Artem, Am never using Shred again. ''blkdiscard''Txs!  ////   Thanks much Sotto.
